# How did this application update itself?

Tags: c#

i have been looking for a way to update my application for ages, and still haven't found a solution. (Please don't say ClickOnce, it isn't suitable for this app).

Years ago i used to use MCadmin to run a Minecraft server, and i remembered that when it started, sometimes it would just say "Update downloaded, please restart!". I have tried to find out how this was done, so i have been looking in the source code and found some things.

Here is some code that i found:

```
private void CheckUpdateThread()
    {
        Program.AddRTLine(Color.Green, "Verifying existence of essential files...\r\n", false);

        if (!File.Exists("ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll"))
            Util.DownloadURLToFile("https://internal.mcadmin.eu/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll", "ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll");
        if (!File.Exists("LICENSE.txt"))
            Util.DownloadURLToFile("https://internal.mcadmin.eu/LICENSE.txt", "LICENSE.txt");

        Program.AddRTLine(Color.Green, "Essential file validation completed!\r\n", false);

        if (Program.dontUpdate)
        {
            Program.AddRTLine(Color.Green, "Update checking disabled!!!\r\n", false); 
            return;
        }

        UpdateRunning = true;

        Program.AddRTLine(Color.Green, "Checking for updates...\r\n", false);

        bool isUpdate;

        if (Program.dontUpdateMCAdmin || 1 == 1)
        {
            Program.AddRTLine(Color.Green, "MCAdmin update checking disabled.\r\n", false);
        }
        else
        {
            isUpdate = Util.DownloadURLToAndDiff("https://internal.mcadmin.eu/MCAdmin.exe", "MCAdmin.exe.new", "MCAdmin.exe");
            if (!isUpdate)
            {
                if (OutOfDateMCA)
                {
                    Program.AddRTLine(Color.Orange, "MCAdmin update downloaded! Restart MCAdmin to apply update!\r\n", false);
                    SendAdminMessage("MCAdmin update downloaded, consider restarting.", 4);
                }
                else
                {
                    Program.AddRTLine(Color.Green, "MCAdmin already up to date!\r\n", false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    if (File.Exists("MCAdmin.exe.old"))
                        File.Delete("MCAdmin.exe.old");
                }
                catch { }
                try
                {
                    if (File.Exists("MCAdmin.exe"))
                        File.Delete("MCAdmin.exe");
                }
                catch { }

                if (File.Exists("MCAdmin.exe")) 
                    File.Move("MCAdmin.exe", "MCAdmin.exe.old");
                File.Move("MCAdmin.exe.new", "MCAdmin.exe");

                OutOfDateMCA = true;
                Program.AddRTLine(Color.Orange, "MCAdmin update downloaded! Restart MCAdmin to apply update!\r\n", false);

                SendAdminMessage("MCAdmin update downloaded, consider restarting.", 4);
            }

        }
```

This code is from a single void in a class called "UpdateManager".

See how it does the whole "MCadmin.exe.old" and "MCadmin.exe.new" files, a bit like shadow copying.

There is more to the updater code, but i don't quite understand.

Here is the SVN:
https://code.google.com/p/mcadminfork/source/browse/

Could anybody help me find out how this updater was acheived?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your exact question? you see in the code, the program downloads its own codebase again and replaces it ... (which is without checking the signature a very high security risk ... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Util.DownloadURLToAndDiff() does the actual downloading and file comparison. So you probably want to look at that.

Otherwise, it's pretty simple:

1. Download MCAdmin.exe.new
2. Delete MCAdmin.exe.old (leftover from previous update)
3. Try to delete current MCAdmin.exe
4. If delete fails (file in use probably), rename MCAdmin.exe MCAdmin.exe.old
5. Rename MCAdmin.exe.new MCAdmin.exe

Comment: Thanks! - I had trouble understanding it, this clears it up now!

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer (http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: OK, oh, 1 more thing, i went on the main form load event, and it doesn't start the Update, where abouts does all the startup stuff happen if its not there?

Comment: A quick search reveals it is instantiated in program.cs on line 197.

Comment: Thanks, but i can't get this to work on WPF, theres just so many Threading problems, like "A different thread owns it", or "Must be STA thread"!